# problem with object files undefined after change bodyparser in app.js in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have the object files undefined after change bodyparser in app.js in nodejs

```
// Middlewares

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
//app.use(fileupload());

//Middlewares deprecated
//  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//  app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I am using express `"express": "^4.16.4",`

How I can setup properly bodyparser to upload an image to nodejs?

room.js controller

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
```

room.js routes

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var md_upload = multipart({ uploadDir: './uploads/rooms' });
router.post('/upload-avatar',  md_upload, RoomController.uploadAvatar);
```

something is very weird with this files undefined

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, no need to use body-parser, its added back again to express

To allow image upload with more size, I recommend you use the limit property and give it a value of like 30MB

for example

```
 app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
 app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
```

This was quoted from body-parser npm

> limit:
> Controls the maximum request body size. If this is a number, then the value specifies the number of bytes; if it is a string, the value
> is passed to the bytes library for parsing. Defaults to '100kb'

Comment: doesnt works TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

     console.log(Object.keys(req.files.file0.path));
     console.log(files);